# Concat error in C#

Tags: c#

I have a quick sort program using lists.

The error is in the quick sort function return statement.

> System.Collections.List does not contain definition for Concat and the best extension method System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerableTsource has some invalid arguments.

The code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the n9o. of elements: ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int> unsorted = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            unsorted.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
        }

        List<int> sorted = quicksort(unsorted);
        foreach (int entry in sorted)
        {
            Console.Write(entry + "\t");
        }

        return;
    } //end of main.

    public static List<int> quicksort(List<int> given)
    {
        if (given.Count == 1)
            return given;
        int mid = given.Count / 2;
        List<int> less = new List<int>();
        List<int> big = new List<int>();
        for (int a = 0; a < given.Count; a++)
        {
            if (given[a] < mid)
            {
                less.Add(given[a]);
            }
            else
                big.Add(given[a]);
        }


        return (quicksort(less).Concat(given[mid]).Concat(quicksort(big)));
    }


}//end of class.

}//end of namespace.
```

Comment: That exception is always accompanied by another one, telling you which best overload it tried and what parameter you supplied. It would be useful if you also provided that error, but I guess it is _"cannot convert from 'int' to 'IEnumerable<int>'"_, which actually tells you the source of the error.

Comment: yes,this is the error.Please tell me how to modify the return statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `Concat` an `int` into an `IEnumerable<int>`. You could instead wrap it in an array and `Concat` that to your other lists:

```
return quicksort(less)
   .Concat(new[] { given[mid] })
   .Concat(quicksort(big))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Note that function using `Concat` should be called "ridiculouslySlowSort" instead :) due to multiple copy operations to create new lists.

Comment: but this gives the error: Cast missing.Cannot convert System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<int> to System.Collections.Generic.List<int>

Comment: Updated - Tim S missed `ToList()`... Also instead you could change signature to `IEnumerable<int> quicksort(IEnumerable<int> given)` and rely on just iteration instead of indexing inside your sorting code.

Comment: Please tell how the ToList() solves the matter.Please.

Comment: @AbhishekJain the error was occurring because the method's return type is `List<int>` while the result of the `Concat` operation is an `IEnumerable<int>`. `ToList()` takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and makes a `List<T>` from it, so it solves the error.

Comment: The compilation goes well but during run time it gives Stackoverflow error.Please help in this too. I will be really grateful.

Comment: @AbhishekJain you should debug your code to figure out what's wrong. As a hint, what is the size of `less` and `big` compared to `given`?

Comment: @AbhishekJain - if you want someone else to write/debug quicksort please use one already available in framework and be done with it - there is absolute no reason to write it the way you've shown except learning how to write/debug/test code.

Answer (score 3):

As the error is trying to tell you, the `Concat()` method takes a *collection* of items to concatenate, not a single `int`.

Comment: so how should the return statement be modified?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding given[mid] to the resulting list is a mistake, since it will add the item to your resulting list twice...

also, you need to test against given[mid] not mid

So you should change your if statement to:

```
        if (given[a] < given[mid])
            less.Add(given[a]);
        else if (given[a] > given[mid])
            big.Add(given[a]);
```

This is assuming that all numbers are unique as well, because if given[mid] is not unique, then you have a problem